# clone a sqlite database skip some data

Tags: sqlite

My application logs user access to sqlite database, the **my.db** file grows about 5Gb every month. There're tables like "**access**" which logs every user access, this table should be cleared at every beginning of the month, and it holds almost all the 5gb data. Another table "**user**" which holds all my users, this table should always keep its data.

So every month I need to:

1. ctrl+c -> ctrl+v **my.db** to clone a file copy(for future statistics), this is very slow for 5gb file.
2. clear the "**access**" table via "**delete from access**" and "**vacuum**", it also takes some time.

It's too slow. I wonder if there is a sql command like "**export/import database structure and indices**" to clone only the structure to another new.db, and then "**copy * from mydb.user to newdb**"

Or maybe some existing tool can do this?

Comment: Use [.schema](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) and [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the sample database I'll use, representing your old database. I made a table to keep, a table to lose, and an index.

```
$ sqlite3 old.db
sqlite> create table KeepMe (a TEXT);
sqlite> create table DeleteMe (b TEXT);
sqlite> create index DeleteMe_b on DeleteMe(b);
sqlite> insert into KeepMe values("Hello");
sqlite> insert into DeleteMe values("World");
sqlite> .quit
```

First copy the schema to a new database:

```
$ sqlite3 old.db .schema | sqlite3 new.db
```

Then open the new database, [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to the old database, and copy over the table(s) you want:

```
$ sqlite3 new.db
sqlite> attach "old.db" as old;
sqlite> insert into KeepMe select * from old.KeepMe;
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE KeepMe (a TEXT);
INSERT INTO "KeepMe" VALUES('Hello');
CREATE TABLE DeleteMe (b TEXT);
CREATE INDEX DeleteMe_b on DeleteMe(b);
COMMIT;
sqlite> .quit
```